# How to generate customize XML Report in squish Qt?

Tags: squish

I am trying to generate custom XML report in squish qt(Python). Help me to generate the report?

Answer (score 0):

Other than adding respective report/log entries via *test.vp()*, *test.log()*, *test.pass()*, etc. Squish does not offer customizing the reports of its report generators.

You can process the resulting reports after they have been generated, using any method or tool known to you. The XML based report variants may lend themselves to this.